# Compatible versions of AUCTeX and Ghostscript on Mac

Tags: emacs, auctex, ghostscript

When I run preview-at-point (in emacs), I get a minus (do not enter) sign rather than the figure.

I followed the suggestion [here](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.bugs/month=20111001) and downloaded the development version of AucTeX. The problem remains.

Is there a way at this time to resolve this issue? I am on OSX, have Ghostscript 9.04, and tried AucTeX 11.86 as well as the development version.

**Edit**
For the sake of those consulting the archives, I have not resolved this issue. Perhaps it's best to just wait for a new release of auctex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Ghostscript version 8.71 (32bit version) for it to work. It can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/files/GPL%20Ghostscript/8.71/).

Comment: This did make a change. Instead of the do-not-enter sign, I now get a tiny square (2x2 pixels?). Magnifying the figure (a pdf file) did not enlarge the square, so it looks like I still have some work to do just to see the figures inside the latex buffer in emacs. Suggestions for debugging what is happening are welcome.